# Tex compiling problem

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, kile

I am using Kile Editor and when I run any `.tex` file, I thought that the `.dvi` file would be auto-generated. Do I have to install anything more in my Linux pc to run the editor successfully?

Here is the code:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plasmati Graduate CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (24/3/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati (alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX.
% The main document font is called Fontin and can be downloaded for free
% from here: http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be \usepackage{fullpage}
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering{\Huge John \textsc{Smith}}\bigskip\par} % Your name

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Canada  | 20 November 1987 \\
\textsc{Address:} & 123 Broadway, City, State, Canada \\
\textsc{Phone:} & +1 111 1112\\
\textsc{email:} & \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Current} & 1\textsuperscript{st} year Analyst at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, London \\
\textsc{Mar 2012} & \emph{Commodities Structured Trading}\\ 
& \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Summer Intern at \textsc{Intech Inc}, Chicago \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jan-Mar 2011} & Computer Technician at \textsc{Buy More}, Burbank \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{July} 2012 & Master of Commerce in \textsc{Finance}, \textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& 110/110 \small\emph{First Class Honours} | Major: Quantitative Finance\\
& Thesis: ``Money is the Root of All Evil - Or is it?'' | \small Advisor: Prof. James \textsc{Smith}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0\hyperlink{grds}{\hfill | \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2011& Undergraduate Degree in \textsc{}\textsc{Business Studies} \\&110/110 \small\emph{Commerce Specialization}, \normalsize\textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& Heavily specialized in mundane paperwork | \small Advisor: Stefano \textsc{Bonini}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 7.5/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Fall} 2008 & Exchange Semester at \textbf{University of Southern California}, Los Angeles\\
& \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2006& \textbf{Liceo Classico ``E. Duni''}, Matera | Final Grade: 100/100
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SCHOLARSHIPS AND ADDITIONAL INFO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Scholarships and Certificates}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Sept.} 2012 & Faculty of Science Masters Scholarship \footnotesize(\$30,000)\normalsize\\

\textsc{June} 2010 & {\textsc{Gmat}\textregistered}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}: 730 (\textsc{q:50;v:39}) 96\textsuperscript{th} percentile; \textsc{awa}: 6.0/6.0 (89\textsuperscript{th} percentile)
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{English:} & Fluent\\

\textsc{Italian:} & Mothertongue\\

\textsc{French:} & Basic Knowledge\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic Knowledge: & \textsc{php}, my\textsc{sql}, \textsc{html}, Access, \textsc{Linux}, ubuntu, {\fb \LaTeX}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}\\

Intermediate Knowledge: & \textsc{vba}, Excel, Word, PowerPoint\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS AND ACTIVITIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests and Activities}

Technology, Open-Source, Programming\\
Paradoxes in Decision Making, Psychoanalysis, Behavioural Finance\\
Football, Travelling

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRADE TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds}{Master of Science in \textsc{Finance}}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade}&\textsc{Credit Hrs}\\ \hline
Corporate Finance (Valuation) & 25 & 6\\
Financial Statement Analysis & 28 & 6\\
Statistics & 27 & 6\\
Theory of Finance & 26 & 6\\
Quantitative Methods for Finance & 30 & 6\\
Econometrics & 24 & 6\\
Derivatives & 31 & 6\\
Management of Financial and Insurance Companies & 30 & 6\\
Business Law & 31 & 6\\
Investment Banking  & 28 & 6\\ \\       
Behavioral Models for Economics and Finance  & 29 & 6\\
Numerical Methods for Finance & 29 & 6\\
Advanced Derivatives & 30 & 6\\
Fixed Income (Advanced Methods) & 30 & 6\\ \\
English Language & 30 & 4\\
French Language & 31 &  4\\ 
Internship & & 8\\      
Final Thesis & & 20\\   
& Total & 120\\\cline{2-3}
&\textsc{Gpa}&\textbf{8.0}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

%------------------------------------------------

\bigskip

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds_usc}{Exchange Program at \textsc{usc}, Los Angeles}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade} & \textsc{Grade Points}\\ 
\hline
Corporate Financial Strategy & A & 4\\
Derivatives & A & 4\\
Money, Credit, and Banking & A & 4\\
Business Strategy & A- & 3.5\\
& &\\\cline{2-3}
& \textsc{Gpa} & \textbf{3.875}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

And Here is the output in my Kile Editor. [image]

Comment: Within Kile: Build > Compile > XeLaTeX. By default, Kile uses pdfLaTeX. That will not work with code which requires one of the newer engines. (`fontspec` is such a package.)

Comment: Have you downloaded the font as required by the comments?
http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html

Comment: I tried to download the fonts but its not working. I am using ubuntu. Is there any way to install these fonts by terminal?

Comment: Use `apt` or `synaptic` or whatever Ubuntu uses as a package manager. They probably offer a package for those fonts.

Comment: @cfr Meow. Wanna answer?

Comment: @cfr If you do, you can close the following as dupe [Problem with fonts and rerunfilecheck package Miktex 2.9 in Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224735)

Comment: @Johannes_B OK. But I don't think my answer here addresses that question because font installation is OS-dependent. I have no idea how to install fonts for Windows!

Comment: @Johannes_B I edited the question a bit. Did I change too much?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem shown by Kile is that the document is being compiled with pdfTeX (which is the default) but it requires one of the newer engines: LuaTeX or XeTeX.

The screen shot shown is not very useful as it only says compilation has failed but not why. To see why, you can click on 'Output` which is more detailed than 'Log and Messages'. This will probably show an informative error message.

The document requires LuaTeX or XeTeX because it loads `fontspec` which depends on one of these engines being used:

```
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
```

To compile with XeTeX, in Kile choose the XeLaTeX from the menu:

> Build > Compile > XeLaTeX

To compile this particular document, you need access to the font family Fontin:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
```

This is not part of TeX Live but XeTeX and LuaTeX can both use the fonts installed system-wide, so the document depends on your having these fonts installed.

If you don't have Fontin already, you can do a couple of things:

### Option 1

Comment out the line which specifies this font:

```
% \setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
```

This will allow the document to compile but it will not look as it is meant to as it will use a different font.

### Option 2

Install the font using your Linux distro's package manager, assuming that a suitable package is available. If this is an option, this is almost certainly the best one.

The way to do this depends entirely on your distro. On Arch Linux, for example, an AUR package is available:

```
aur/ttf-exljbris 1.1-4 (52, 0.60)
    A collection of free opentype fonts by Jos Buivenga. Includes Delicious, Diavlo, Fontin, Fontin Sans and Tallys
```

so I would use that. You should search for packages using whatever method you usually use (`synaptic` or `apt` or whatever) and install the fonts that way if possible.

### Option 3

Failing that, you have to download and install the fonts yourself.

- How best to do this is somewhat dependent on your distro. On Arch, for example, I would probably make a package to install the fonts into `/usr/share/fonts`.
- If that's not a good option for you, you should ***not*** install manually into this directory. Instead, you should use `/usr/local/share/fonts`. There will also be a directory you can use in your home directory. The precise locations of these directories depend on how `fontconfig` is configured for your Linux distro and/or customised for your system.
- Once in place, you will need to update the font caches before the fonts will be recognised. `fc-cache` is used for this purpose in many cases e.g. `fc-cache -s` for the system font caches or `fc-cache <path to directory>` if using, say, the user font directory in home. One way to figure out the right incantation is to just see what scripts packages run when they install fonts for your system and adapt accordingly.

Comment: Good answer with respect to a *template* question. The template site clearly says the fonts have to be installed. If a user is to dumb to read some introductory material, searches for a template and doesn't even read those few sentences, there really is no help.

Comment: Another template on that site states: "If you run into problems, update your system before you ask a question." Stil, i quite often get people who just are too lazy to read.