# Problem with fonts and rerunfilecheck package Miktex 2.9 in Windows

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm trying to compile a document that I download from here:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv

It works on one computer, but not in my new PC.
The error comes from

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font

\begin{document}

\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin-SmallCaps.otf]{Fontin.otf}\\

\end{document}
```

The xelatex says:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty")TFM file 
C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/tfm//OT.tfm already exists.
xelatex.EXE: The font file could not be found.
xelatex.EXE: Data: [Fontin.otf]/OT
texify: xelatex failed for some reason (see log file).
```

And the `.log` file say:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Feature \pdfmdfivesum is not available
(rerunfilecheck)             (e.g. pdfTeX or LuaTeX with package `pdftexcmds').

(rerunfilecheck)             Therefore file contents cannot be checked efficien
tly
(rerunfilecheck)             and the loading of the package is aborted.
)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please provide a small, compilable document demonstrating the issue in your question. A question needs to stand on its own independent of external links which may later change or disappear. Otherwise, your question will be of limited use to future viewers. That part of the log is just giving you information. No error is given there. And how does that relate to the title of your question?

Comment: Thak you very much, I think now is better. I hope that the .log that I edit is the problem.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that your question needs to be self-contained. Not only does this make it easier to help you. It also ensures it remains useful for future users, even if external links change or disappear.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was in the font Fontin.otf. I have just intalled the font from here https://github.com/fayimora/cv/blob/master/Fontin.otf  and now it works. Thank you very much for all of your help cfr.